# Single svn repository for all composer packages

Tags: php, svn, composer-php, package, tortoisesvn

I'm about to do a project by splitting modules as a separate composer packages. My own private repository.

I'm planning to use single repository for all my packages.

```
https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/
```

I will separate modules this way. So I can have separate branch and tag for each module.

```
https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleA/trunk/
https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleA/tags/
https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleA/branches/

https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleC/trunk/
https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleC/tags/
https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleC/branches/
```

I will add each repositories this way

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleA",
            "trunk-path": "trunk",
            "branches-path": "branches",
            "tags-path": "tags"
        },
        {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "https://myhost.com/svn/myrepo/moduleC",
            "trunk-path": "trunk",
            "branches-path": "branches",
            "tags-path": "tags"
        }
    ]
}
```

Will composer work with this type of svn pattern ?